Is the condition of the concrete under this steel post a concern?
I am interested in your opinion about this post beside the cold room in the basement.
Is the structure of the concrete deteriorating? Is it supporting this pole well? By the pattern of the wall right under, it looks like there was a leak there or something that was cleaned.



is this an exterior wall

someone cut out a slot in the plate and then put in this loose steel post through a hole in the floor.  it makes no sense.

This looks highly suspicious to me. It looks like there was a good size crack in the wall that was patched with some epoxy or foam type sprayed material and then covered over with a concrete patch material. It doesn't appear to be a professional job. The concrete at the base of the pole does not seem to be adequately supported. I would be getting this professionally inspected.

Yup I would say there are some curious issues there. It has held up this long, but definately needs to be looked at by a person who can determine what is going on there.

Yeah, looks to me like that was patched already.  Could be simply incomplete vibration of the concrete when pouring the wall, but who knows?

I don't see any problems.

The concrete under the post has a compressive strength far exceeding what's needed to support the post.

The minor void seems to be the result of a sloppy pour, possibly because the form restricted access to that corner of the wall. It doesn't look like degradation to me, but just a poor finish there.

Whatever's going on with the repair below is vertical, so it's not likely a structural issue if the wall isn't significantly displaced. It looks like an attempt to waterproof the joint between two different pours (which explains the offset at the top).



the only issue I can see is that typically the base of a column needs to be bolted to the support to prevent any displacement in a seismic event.  I've had the inspector make the column base bear onto the footing and have the slab cover up over top.

How do you know what strength is needed to support that post? Do we know what's resting on it? (E.g., a condo high-rise in Florida?)

There's nothing that would reasonably be resting on that particular residential-type post that concrete couldn't handle.

Given that the sill plate is bolted with a bigass bolt, why wouldn't you want the post to be similarly fastened?

You would, but I don't see a good way to do that and that wasn't the question. FWIW, that looks like a fairly small bolt. They're usually 1/2" or better. This looks like about 3/8".
